# Find general solution for $y'' - y = xe^{x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The initial conditions are $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(0) = 1$. I know from previous problems that the solutions for $y'' - y = x$ and $y'' - y = e^{x}$ are $y_g(x) = -x$ and $y_g(x) = c_1e^{x} + c_2e^{-x} + \frac{1}{2}xe^{x}$ so naturally I would multiply both $y_g$'s to get

$$y_g(x) = -c_1xe^{x} - c_2xe^{-x} - \frac{1}{2}x^2 e^{x} $$

However this is giving me issues because now I can't use $y_g$ to solve for a particular solution when $y(0) = 0$ and I can't solve the system of equations anymore.

Comment: First solve $y''-y=0$. The general solution is the complementary function. Then try $y_p=(Ax^2+Bx)e^x$ for the particular integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no reason to think (and it's not true) that if you multiply solutions like you do, you'll get a solution. In this particular case it seems to give something more or less similar, but in general you'll get something completely different. For instance consider 
$$
y''-y=x,\ \ y''-y=\tfrac1x,\ \ \ y''-y=1. 
$$
Particular solutions are, respectively, $y_1(x)=-x$, $y_2(x)=(e^x\operatorname{Ei}(-x)+e^{-x}\operatorname{Ei}(x))/2$, $y_3(x)=-1$. The product of the first two solutions is nowhere close to being a solution to the third equation.

To look for a particular solution in you case, you could  use Undetermined Coefficients: you take $y(x)=Ax^2e^x+Bxe^x$ (you need to go "up" to $x^2$ because $e^x$ is a solution of the homogeneous part). When you substitute in the equation you get 
$$
xe^x=y''-y=  4A xe^x + 2(A + B)e^x.
$$
So $A=1/4$ and $B=-A=-1/4$. This gives you, as a general solution,
$$
y(x)=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+\frac{(x^2-x)e^x}4
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Considering the equation $$y'' - y = xe^{x}$$ start using $y=z\,e^x$. This gives
$$z''+2 z'=x$$ Now, reduction fo order $p=z'$ gives
$$p'+2p=x$$ which is simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use inverse laplace transform of derivatives to solve for particular solution directly. After obtaining function f(t), you have to check whether it is of exponential order and is piecewise continuous of every subinterval of zero to infinity, then only we can guarantee that it's laplace transform exists.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'' - y = xe^{x}$$
$$r^2-1=0 \implies r=\pm 1 $$
The solution to the homogeneous equation is :
$$y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}$$

For the particular solution, try $y_p=x(ax+b)e^x$
$$y'_p=(2ax+b)e^x+(ax^2+bx)e^x$$
$$y''_p=2ae^x+2(2ax=b)e^x+(ax^2+bx)e^x$$
Therefore
$$y''=y=xe^x \implies $$
$$2ae^x+2(2ax=b)e^x+(ax^2+bx)e^x-x(ax+b)e^x=xe^x$$
$$4ax+2a+2b=x \implies (a,b)=(\frac 14,-\frac 14)$$
Therefore the solution is:
$$y=c_1e^x+c_2e^{-x}+\dfrac x 4(x-1)e^x$$
Apply initial condition
$$y(0)=0 \implies c_1=-c_2$$
And
$$y'(0)=1 \implies c_1=\dfrac 5 8,c_2=-\dfrac 5 8$$
Therefore the solution to the DE is
$$\boxed {y(x)=\dfrac 5 8 (e^x-e^{-x})+\dfrac {x e^x}4(x-1)}$$